# Visit /opt/gopath/src/chaincode failed: lstat /opt/gopath/src/chaincode: no such file or directory

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

cli's setting:

```
   container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    networks:
        - basic
```

I have no idea about it~ Could someone give me a hint~please

Comment: change /opt/gopath/src/github.com/ to /opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode on your volume path

Answer (score 0):

peer container doesn't have /opt/gopath/src/chaincode path

and in cli, the "volume":
"./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/"
which means the relationship between docker container path and project path

so I should change /opt/gopath/src/chaincode to /opt/gopath/src/github.com/